# Display notification alert when the app is in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I can get the push notification message in this method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
}
```

But the problem is how to display an alert notification when the app is runing as the same way it displayed when the app is in background.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

When the app in foreground, you only get the callback, iOS doesn't show alert in that case, you have to do it yourself...

You can do it like this:

Create a nib for the 'PN foreground view', for example:

[image]

And when you get a PN in foreground, you can instantiate the view, and add it to the UIWindow with animation, code for example:

```
        // init and configure your custom PN foreground view
        let nib = UINib(nibName: self.nibName, bundle: NSBundle(forClass: PnForegroundView))
        pnForegroundView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! PnForegroundView
        pnForegroundView.setWidth(UIScreen.width)
        pnForegroundView.setHeight(63)
        pnForegroundView.title = <some title from notification>
        pnForegroundView.image = <some image from notification>

        // add the view to the key window 
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
        window.addSubview(pnForegroundView!)

        // Change window level to hide the status bar
        window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar

        // Show the PN foreground view with animation:

        self.pnForegroundView!.setBottom(0)
        self.changeWindowLevelToHideStatusBar()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
            self.pnForegroundView!.setBottom(self.pnForegroundView!.height)
        }
```

Of course, you should set a delegate for this view, for case user clicking the notification, and when the user dismisses it.

Also, you can add time for automatic dismissal.

Last thing - when removing the `PnForegroundView`, you better reset your `UIWindow` level to default value, for showing the status bar

Answer (score 2):

Adding that completionHandler line to appDelegate method worked for me:

```
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)

completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

didReceiveRemoteNotification will trigger no matter whether you are foreground or in background Though, you can handle them seperately as below

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let state = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState
        if state == UIApplicationState.Active {
            //show alert here your app is in foreground
        }
        else{
            //your app is in background
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yeah i know, but i want to display the same alert notification displayed when the app is in background

Comment: Buddy when app is in background and is still active you can create a local notification and throw it :) it will look absolutely like remote notification you can even handle badge count as well :) but when user taps on the notification you will get control in didRecieveLocalNotification method that's all :)

Comment: I already did that, i don't get banner alert, it's just displayed into the notification center without any sound or alert

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/sandeeplearner/SBNotificationBar I have written it on my own might help you to do what you want :) here is the explaination and how it looks like http://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2016/01/sbnotificationbar-custom-notification.html